# Fatal Error - Call to undefined method "Customersss::throwError()"

Tags: php

I created a class and try to call in a method, but however in my **error log**, I am getting response `"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Customersss::throwError()"`, please what am I doing wrong, because I know I have created `throwError()`, I can't seem to be able to access the class.

Firstly the class trying to call **object**

```
$this->throwError(INVALID_DATA_TTT, "Invalid shipping fee"); //WHERE I SUSPECT ERROR IS BEING GENERATED
```

The full error

```
   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
   Customersss::throwError() in
   /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/customers.php:276 Stack
   trace:
   #0 /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/api.php(177): Customersss->insertNewDelivery()
   #1 [internal function]: Api->create_insert_new_delivery()
   #2 /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/rest.php(42): ReflectionMethod->invoke(Object(Api))
   #3 /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/index.php(4): Rest->processApi()
   #4 {main}   thrown in /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/customers.php on line 276
```

customers.php

```
require_once('constants.php');
require_once('rest.php');   
class Customersss {     
private $id;
private $shipping_fee;
private $pickup_fee; 

function setId($id){ $this->id = $id; }
function getId() { return $this->id; }

function setShipping_fee($shipping_fee){ $this->shipping_fee = $shipping_fee; }
function getShipping_fee() { return $this->shipping_fee; }

function setPickup_fee($pickup_fee){ $this->pickup_fee = $pickup_fee; }
function getPickup_fee() { return $this->pickup_fee; }

public function __construct(){
$db = new DbConnect();
$this->dbConn = $db->connect();
}

public function insertNewDelivery(){
if ($this->shipping_fee == ""){
$this->throwError(EMPTY_PARAMETER, "Empty shipping fee");
exit();
}   

if ($this->shipping_fee == ""){
$this->throwError(INVALID_DATA_TTT, "Invalid shipping fee");
exit();
}   
}


}
```

rest.php

```
 require_once('constants.php');
    class Rest {
    protected $request;
    protected $serviceName;
    protected $param;

      public function processApi(){
      $api = new API;
      $rMethod = new reflectionMethod('API', $this->serviceName);
      if(!method_exists($api, $this->serviceName)){
      $this->throwError(API_DOST_NOT_EXIST, "API does not exist");
       }
        $rMethod->invoke($api);
    }

    public function throwError($code, $message){
         header("content-type: application/json");
         $errorMsg = json_encode(['error' => ['status'=>$code, 'message'=>$message]]);
         echo $errorMsg; exit;       
    }
    }
```

constants.php

```
 define('INVALID_DATA_TTT',          350);
     define('EMPTY_PARAMETER',           404);
     define('API_DOST_NOT_EXIST',        400);
     define('ACCESS_TOKEN_ERRORS',       500);
```

api.php

```
require_once "customers.php";
require_once "constants.php";

class Api extends Rest {
public $dbConn;  

public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();  
$db = new DbConnect;
$this->dbConn = $db->connect();

}
  public function create_insert_new_delivery(){
  $shipping_fee= $this->validateParameter('item_category', $this->param['shipping_fee'], STRING, true);


  try {
 $cust = new Customersss;
 }  catch (Exception $e){
 $this->throwError(ACCESS_TOKEN_ERRORS, $e->getMessage());

}
}
```

Comment: Well, `Customersss` doesn't have a `throwError` method. You're trying to call it as `$this->throwError(INVALID_DATA_TTT, "Invalid shipping fee");` at the end  of the `insertNewDelivery` method.

Comment: `throwError` is defined in `Rest`, and would exist in `Api` as it extends `Rest`. However, `Customer` does not extend either, so it would not have access to that function as a class function.

Comment: @aynber Please how do i create it in I mean throwError have been trying it since the whole not working

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Please how do i create it in I mean throwError have been trying it since the whole not working

Comment: You already did it in `Rest`, what's the problem?

Comment: You can either add the function to `Customers` as it exists in `Rest`, or you can have `Customers` extend either `Rest` or `Api`, depending on what you want your structure to look like. Or you can create a new `Rest` or `Api` object within `Customers`, and call that function.

Comment: @aynber "You can either add the function to Customers as it exists in Rest" Please can you show me an example cause I have done that and its not working

Comment: @federicoklezculloca It is not connecting I just dont know why, it is giving error, it should work

Comment: Copy the function from Rest, paste it into Customers. If that's not working, let us know what about it is not working.

Comment: @aynber Let me do that

Comment: @aynber It is working, I just added the function from Rest Thank you

Comment: @federicoklezculloca It is working, I just added the function from Rest Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `Rest::ThrowError()` from `Customersss` class. It means your function is unreachable in this context.
To call this `Rest` method from the `Customersss` class, you can:

- extend `Rest` to `Customersss` (see [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php))
- make `ThrowError()` a static method (see [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php))

**Using inheritance:**

```
class Customersss extends Rest { /* your properties/methods */ }
```

**Using a static method:**

```
class Rest {
    static public function throwError($code, $message){ /* your code */ }
}
```

Callable with `Rest::ThrowError()`